# Populate a jTable Using MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jtable, populate

I have a project with a `jTable` called `AchTable`, that is like this:

```
+-------+------+
| File  | Type |
+-------+------+
|       |      |
|       |      |
|       |      |
+--------------+
```

And I have a mySQL table that is like the same, then I want to know how could I populate the `jTable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what is the problem, creating a table or creating an SQL query?

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html).

Read the tutorial on [JDBC Database Access](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/).

Put the two together and you've got your problem solved. That is first create your query and create a ResultSet. Then you use the meta data to get the column names. Then you loop through the ResultSet and add rows of data to your table. You can use a DefaultTableModel for this.